# What is the Jacobi-Anger expansion of the $k$'th functional iterate of the sine function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, fourier-series, trigonometric-series

The Jacobi-Anger [expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%E2%80%93Anger_expansion) gives expressions for functional iterates of trigonometric functions in terms of Bessel functions. For instance, we have $$\sin(z \sin(\theta)) = 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} J_{2n-1} (z) \sin[(2n-1)\theta] .$$
If we plug in $z=1$, we obtain an expression for $\sin(\sin(\theta)) := \sin^{[2]}(\theta)$. We might call this the second functional iterate of the sine function.

Are Jacobi-Anger expansions for $\sin^{[k]}(\theta)$ also known, for arbitrary $k>2$?